# How build dockerfile with few needed ports

Tags: docker, apache, dockerfile, centos8, webmin

I want to learn Docker so I decided to create all files (Dockerfile, docker-compose) step by step by my own.

I need Centos 8 with httpd and webmin. I prepared Dockerfile with httpd and it works very well but when I am trying add RUN with install webmin cmd I can’t figure how open webmin panel. Port 10000 doesn’t work or it works but I don’t know how to get there.

Also, If I need Centos 8 with phpmyadmin, webmin, apache etc. should I create docker-compose with Centos 8 and phpmyadmin separately? Or another way?

My Dockerfile

```
FROM    centos:8
RUN     yum update -y && yum install -y \
        httpd \
        httpd-tools \
        wget \
        perl \
        perl-Net-SSLeay \
        openssl perl-Encode-Detect
RUN wget https://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/webadmin/webmin-1.930-1.noarch.rpm \
&& rpm -U webmin-1.930-1.noarch.rpm

EXPOSE 80

CMD     ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

Comment: Why not use existing images? Most of them share their Dockerfile, such that you could also check how they solved the problem

Comment: I want to understand it. Write Dockerfile by myself is the best practice for me. In addiction, I didn't find any Dockerfile which will be identical to it what I need to use.

Comment: Then please share more details. As you haven't shared a single line of your configuration, it's close to impossible to tell you where it's going wrong

Comment: You shouldn't be running webmin in docker. This is not a VM. It is intended to be configured in the dockerfile and then used to run a single process. It is not intended for use with long-running processes either -- it's designed to be ephemeral primarily for use in distributed systems. Each container is intended to be identical. Webmin is a really old-fashioned approach to server admin that docker is meant to replace.

Comment: The port `10000` is not exposed. You need to expose the port on the image (not mandatory, but very good practice) and publish it during creation of the container (mandatory)

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer thank you very much for ur comment. I need centos 8 with webmin to run php project which has to be always online. What should I do in your opinion? Only centos8 with a needded packages as one Dockerfile or more than one and prepare docker-compose?

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski I added EXPOSE 10000 under 80 and build contaner: ````docker run -d -p 8080:80 -p 20000:10000```` image but port 20000 doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure you have something running in the container that is listening on port 10000? Make sure that you have a process that is listening on the port.

Comment: The problem may be related to that webmin is not running under apache, which means you are launching the process for webmin which listens to port `1000`

Comment: You should build your php project into the docker image using the dockerfile, configuring all the things you'd normally do with webmin in code instead. You should have 1 container per main process (so, 1 per app, 1 for a db (if you have one)).

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer these prepared containers should I use on centos8 server or I should also have Dockerfile with OS? I don't want to use webmin but I must do it. I was thinking about Docker because I want to prepare one docker-compose which will prepare everything to need to start php project. Easy, quicly and the most important - good.

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski webmin's default port is 10000 but in container when I want to check open ports I don't see exposed 10000. I am trying open in with firewall-cmd but I have DBUS_ERROR failed to connect to socket.

Comment: You absolutely do not need webmin -- it does nothing that can't be achieved in the dockerfile. What's more -- you must not use webmin as it's both completely pointless and violates the 'single main process' rule. If you're using that then you should completely give up on docker because those two technologies are in conflict.

Comment: Docker images don't have an OS, they have libraries, sometimes taken from a distro (the FROM line). This isn't a VM. You really need to read a lot more before tackling this and you need to see how other people have done it because you're spending a lot time trying things that will not work well (e.g. webmin)

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer ok, now I understand more. Thank you very much for your comments. I really appreciate that :)